# DIsable Python module

Tags: python

Is there any way to disable a module from being loaded on my system? Let's say i would like to restrict my users from accessing the subprocess or popen2 module. Something like PHP's 'disabled_functions' or any similar method to achieve the same thing.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it (and it is in PHP as well). You shouldn't blacklist certain modules, but whitelist the ones known to be safe. Otherwise, any oversight by you, or any change in package configuration (including packages installed by your users!) could cause a vulnerability.

Comment: What you really want to do is 'sandbox' the code, which can be surprisingly difficult - there are lots of unexpected ways to work around naive limitations. Beware of attempts to use `eval()` or `exec` to do nasty things; to run code that undoes the sandboxing; etc.

Comment: take a look at PyPy's sandboxing features http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/sandbox.html

Comment: @Thomas : google app engine seeems to think otherwise, and they look to be successful.

Comment: @user2284570: App Engine also forbids importing native C modules, so then everything that doesn't go through "known bad" modules remains safely inside the Python sandbox.

Comment: @Thomas : no it doesn’t do it at all *(only custom C modules are not allowed)*. They only prevent importing certain paths from python code *(you can use`dlopen()`from native ᴄᴘᴜ instructions)*. So this isn’t the wrong way… it can be done right. Because they don’t care if a user runs native ᴄᴘᴜ instructions *(I’m not talking about the flexible environment)*. The real concerns is about users mis-using modules they think to be dangerous by design. Their ᴏꜱ level sandbox disallow many system calls. Gaining the possibility to run arbitrary native assembly doesn’t allow to access other’s projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas points out, blacklisting is a pretty poor mechanism for implementing any security mechanisms. Whitelisting is a much safer approach.

But a mechanism inside the interpreter isn't particularly excellent for any number of reasons: flaws in the interpreter that are exploitable at the source code level would allow users to walk right past any mechanisms built in at that level (and the PHP team asked Linux vendors to stop calling this a *security problem*, because (a) they fixed one of these every week and (b) trying to confine an untrusted user-supplied script is pretty much an impossible task -- use FastCGI or similar tools for potentially untrusted scripts).

The Python interpreter is probably not designed to handle malicious input, so don't treat it as such.

If you really want to confine what untrusted users can do with Python scripts, a few pieces of advice: Do not use mod_python or anything like it. Use FastCGI or similar tools that you let specify the *user account* that should run the script and won't execute the script as your webserver user. And learn how to configure SELinux or AppArmor to confine what that process can do -- an hour setting up one of these tools might save you huge headaches down the road, plus you get to laugh at all the cute little exploit attempts that fail.

Comment: It seems google app engine have a pretty secure blacklist.

Comment: @user2284570, GAE's security mechanisms are well worth studying in depth: http://www.security-explorations.com/materials/se-2014-02-report.pdf -- there's mixtures of whitelisting and OS sandboxing going on in addition to JVM security policies.

Comment: I was talking only about the python environment. Where there’s no ᴊᴠᴍ. The paper you linked is completely unrelated *(because the technologies used are different)*. In the case of python, it’s a blacklist : they don’t care if peoples run C code *(as you are an unprivileged user you can only access what you can access with python, so this doesn’t gives more privileges)*. They only blacklist module paths *(I can load the ɢɴᴜ gconv shared object files which are completely outside the python installation)*.

Comment: Modules get backlisted because they think they are dangerous *(it’s for protecting users, not themselves)*.